# replacing values of a few columns in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like below

```
dt <- data.table(x = c("name",NA), y = c("2020-12-31T00:00:00.000+00:00",NA), z = c("2019-12-31T00:00:00.000+00:00
",NA))
```

I want to replace the values of column 2 and 3 in row 2 with values from the the same columns of the first row but only the first 10 characters of its values [substr(.,1:10)]

Answer (score 2):

We could do

```
library(data.table)
dt[, (2:ncol(dt)) := lapply(.SD, \(x) replace(x, 2,
       substr(first(x), 1, 10))), .SDcols = -1]
```

Or use `set`

```
for(j in 2:ncol(dt)) set(dt, i = 2L, j = j,  substr(first(dt[[j]]), 1, 10))
```

Comment: That's perfect. How can I exclude the first column instead of using 2:3 (the length of table is keep changing in real problem)

Comment: I don't see anywhere you specified the row 2 that need to be replaced from values of row 1. Because that's the case for my problem. I don't want other rows values changes. also, can't tell where you are using row 1 data not other rows if I have to say trying to replace values in row 10 from row 1.